# Winter Bash Leader-board search bar not working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, winterbash-leaderboard

Since now Winter Bash has ended, we can't see each others hats. But supposedly in the Winter Bash Leader-board you can search users by their name and see how many hats they got. But I tried searching [here](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com) on SO for some users (I didn't even mention that there isn't any search bar for SE network-wide), and it doesn't affect the page at all, I didn't get any result...

I searched Jon Skeet, but all it does is just loads and stops and nothing changes...

[image: 1]

I suspect this is a bug. Now the search function is needed because we can't see the hats on the profile page anymore, only on the leader-board.

Comment: Scroll down.. It's there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a result, But it's so down, you think it doesn't affect the page..

When I search Jon skeet at the Stackoverflow leaderboard, and scroll down, It is there.

[image]

Comment: Didn't see that !